# Opencv Profilg with Gprof

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, profiling, gprof

I am using opencv in my application and trying to profile my code..To know which function is taking much time.But when I use Gprof to profile my code it is not giving me the time taken by Opencv functions which are internally called by user functions...and my code is in C++

Can any one help me how to get opencv functions Profiling.I am using eclipse gprof plug-in for profiling.

Comment: Don't use `gprof`. It's everywhere and it's venerable, but it's not very good, for many reasons. Get a wall-time stack-sampler like [*Zoom*](http://www.rotateright.com/), or even better, in my experience, [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Comment: afaik, gprof can't look into so/dll's. you'd have to do a static rebuild of the opencv libs, but i doubt if it's worth the hassle